# netplan + WiFi: link is not ready (18.04 Server)

Tags: networking, server, netplan

I'm trying 18.04 Server with this fancy new netplan and can't get my WiFi to work. Doing it the [old-fashioned way](https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/ubuntu-server-16-04-wifi-wpa-supplicant) (e.g. configuring wpa_supplicant.service and using dhclient), everything is fine. But with netplan I get syslog messages saying `IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready` and networkctl has interface wlp2s0 as "no-carrier" and "configuring". Here's the relevant part of my `01-netcfg.yaml` file:

[Edit, see update below]

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Edit1, due to comments ======================

[Edit, see update below]

So chili555 seems to be wrong about IPv6, error persists even with static config. And George, the debug output looks OK to me. Also, the gateway should not be an issue right now, but yes, I use the last IP in the network...

Output of netplan --debug apply

```
** (generate:3281): DEBUG: 19:10:34.892: Processing input file //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml..
** (generate:3281): DEBUG: 19:10:34.892: starting new processing pass
** (generate:3281): DEBUG: 19:10:34.892: wlp2s0: adding wifi AP 'MY_ESSID'
** (generate:3281): DEBUG: 19:10:34.892: enp3s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:3281): DEBUG: 19:10:34.892: wlp2s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:3281): DEBUG: 19:10:34.892: Generating output files..
** (generate:3281): DEBUG: 19:10:34.893: NetworkManager: definition enp3s0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:3281): DEBUG: 19:10:34.893: wlp2s0: Creating wpa_supplicant configuration file run/netplan/wpa-wlp2s0.conf
** (generate:3281): DEBUG: 19:10:34.893: Creating wpa_supplicant service enablement link /run/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/netplan-wpa@wlp2s0.service
** (generate:3281): DEBUG: 19:10:34.893: NetworkManager: definition wlp2s0 is not for us (backend 1)
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration exists, restarting networkd
DEBUG:no netplan generated NM configuration exists
DEBUG:device lo operstate is unknown, not replugging
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:replug wlp2s0: unbinding 0000:02:00.0 from /sys/bus/pci/drivers/iwlwifi
DEBUG:replug wlp2s0: rebinding 0000:02:00.0 to /sys/bus/pci/drivers/iwlwifi
DEBUG:device enp3s0 operstate is up, not replugging
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for enp3s0
```

=== Edit 2 due to comments

New .yaml fragment with dhcp4/6 ABOVE addresses, even though it works fine for Ethernet. Still in networkctl: No-carrier/configuring

```
  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
        - 172.20.12.195/24
        - fd13:4630:2901:12::195/64
      gateway4: 172.20.12.254
      access-points:
        "MyESSID":
          password: "MyPassword"
```

Also, sorry, but honestly: WTF? "Watch your indentation"? Where are we, grammar school? Is it supposed to stay like this? Especially since the (alternate) installer doesn't even give me the chance to configure networking during the installation if it detects DHCP...

=== Edit 3 due to sheer frustration

Just reinstalled (maybe my manual tinkering broke something) and took the setup-generated .yaml file as a template, so now it looks like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: yes
  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      access-points:
        "MyESSID":
          password: "MyPassword"
```

Still no luck, so please stop talking about the order of entries and indentation and stuff, I think it's just plain broken. At least in the alternate installer version of 18.04 server. Next stop: live-server install...

Comment: Move the `dhcp6` entry above the `addresses` entry.

Comment: Also change that `dhcp6: no` to `dhcp: false`. I see no and false but offical doc says it's a boolean!

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. But I noticed that I get syslog messages `WARNING:Unknown index 6 seen, reloading interface list`with the numer always increasing??

Comment: Also changed `dhcp6 no` to `false`  even though it works for the Ethernet interface, still no luck

Comment: Please check your indentation! And is that gateway correct should it not be `172.20.12.1`?

Comment: "IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready" simply means that since you have not asked for an IPv6 address by DHCP and you have also not specified a *static* IPv6 address, you haven't gotten any. It is entirely the expected behavior with regard to IPv6.

Comment: @chili555 should `dhcp: false` not prevent that? In any case if your getting that then it means you indentation isn't ok perhaps you should run netplan like this `sudo netplan --debug apply`!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Not AFAIK. If you don't specify a method to get an IPv6 address, either DHCP or static; or else none is given because the router or ISP doesn't support it, you get the informational message. I don't believe it is a symptom of anything wrong. Even on a system where IPv6 is working correctly, there are lots of informative messages like: "IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready"

Comment: @OttoEisen you did not move the `dhcp` entries above the address entry like I suggested! Please do that as I suspect that those need to be implemented before the address part!

Comment: What does 'iwconfig' show when this happens?  'no-carrier' / 'configuring' implies that networkd thinks based on the kernel state that the interface is not ready to pass traffic.  It may be a driver bug, or there may be something else at play.  Also, what is the intended resulting configuration on this network interface - static ipv4 and ipv6 with no other addresses?

Comment: @slangasek: I've already given up and will try the "live-server" image. But it's not a driver issue, since doing it old-school calling "wpa_supplicant" manually it get an association to my AP and can use "dhclient" to get an IP from my AP.. Anyway, I'll report back with the new installation...

Comment: That does not prove that it's not a driver issue.  networkd is more strict about checking the state of the network interface before proceeding with various operations, whereas dhclient does not check this at all but will just attempt to send traffic which may succeed.  The live-server image uses the same technology as the classic server image, so the outcome is very unlikely to be different using a different install method.

Comment: I'm not 100% certan, but I think it at least had a different netplan File, something about "cloud-inet" or something? Anyways, the weekend will tell....

Comment: I stand corrected, it may actually be a driver issue. I tried CentOS yesterday and also got very strange results: The GUI installer connects fine and gets IPs. But when rebooting after installation I got the same "link is not ready" message. Maybe I should deactivate Network Manager and stick with the "old school", static configuration?